# performance issue using createNativeQuery

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, ejb

I have a performance issue, but, despite what it suggests in the subject, it may not be that I am using createNativeQuery. I have one fairly large query that I pass as a string to createNativeQuery. The query contains several JOINs, and is associated with 5 entities. The query takes, on average, 20 - 25 seconds to run. I have experimented, like trying the createQuery method and using the setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT), setMaxResults() and setFirstResult() methods, but made no difference.

We are using JBoss EAP 6.2 in a JTA container-managed environment, using EJB 3.0, JPA 2.1, Hibernate 4.2. The IDE I use is NetBeans 8.0.2

Yet, if I run the query directly in a SQL tool like DB Visualizer it takes milliseconds. I suspect it might have something to do with Hibernate, but am not sure. None of the Entity classes contains a collection, although there are specific relationships between the tables, as indicated in the JOIN statements in the query. I have attached some code (including the query) below.

I am hoping to retain the query as-is, but if a suggestion is made that would make it more efficient I am open to that. I appreciate that it might be difficult to answer since the query below may be difficult to analyze without knowing the database schema (this is a company project, so can only provide pseudo code in some instances). I have also not provided the Entity or Facade classes, but can provide those later if necessary. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
public List<String> searchSingleView (String sourceSystem, String sourceClientId, String convertedClientId, String policyNum) {

   String sqlQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT " +
      "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.ROWID_XREF, " +                                      "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_CONTRACT.LAST_ROWID_SYSTEM, " +
                                    "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_CONTRACT.SRC_POLICY_ID, " +
                                    "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_CONTRACT.ISSUE_DT, " +
                                    "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.SRC_CLIENT_ID, " +
                                    "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.PERS_FULL_NAME_TXT, " +
                                    "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.PERS_SRC_NAME_TXT, " +
                                    "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.ORG_LEGAL_NAME_TXT, " +
                                    "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.ORG_SRC_NAME_TXT, " +
                                    "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.ORG_LEGAL_SFX_TXT, " +
                                    "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.ORG_NAME_TXT, " +
                                    "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.SIN_BIN_TEXT, " +
                                    "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.PERS_BIRTH_DT, " +
                                    "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR_XREF.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, " +
                                    "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR_XREF.COMPLETE_ADDRESS_TXT, " +
                                    "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR_XREF.TOPLINE_POSTAL_ADDR_TXT, " +
                                    "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR_XREF.CITY_NAME, " +
                                    "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR_XREF.COUNTRY_NAME, " +
                                    "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR_XREF.POSTAL_CD, " +
                                    "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR_XREF.POSTAL_ADDR_PURPOSE_CD, " +
                                    "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR_XREF.STATE_PROVINCE_NAME, " +
                                    "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR_XREF.BAD_ADDR_IND " +
                                    "FROM MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF " +
                                    "LEFT JOIN MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR_XREF ON " + 
                                    "(MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR_XREF.S_PARTY_ROWID = MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.SRC_CLIENT_ID " +
                                        "OR MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR_XREF.S_PARTY_ROWID = MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.CONVERTED_CLIENT_ID) " +      
                                    "LEFT JOIN MDMCUST_ORS.C_LU_CODES ON MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR_XREF.POSTAL_ADDR_PURPOSE_CD = MDMCUST_ORS.C_LU_CODES.CODE " +
                                    "LEFT JOIN MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_REL ON MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.ROWID_OBJECT = MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_REL.FROM_PARTY_ROWID " +
                                    "LEFT JOIN MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_CONTRACT ON MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_REL.CONTRACT_ROWID = MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_CONTRACT.ROWID_OBJECT " +
                                "WHERE MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_CONTRACT.LAST_ROWID_SYSTEM IN ('E-CAPSIL', 'C-CAPSIL', 'INGENIUM') " +
                                    "AND (UPPER(MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.SRC_CLIENT_ID) = ? " +
                                    "     OR UPPER(MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.CONVERTED_CLIENT_ID) = ? " +
                                    "     ) " +
                                    "AND UPPER(MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_CONTRACT.SRC_POLICY_ID) = ? " +
                                    "AND MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR_XREF.POSTAL_ADDR_PURPOSE_CD = '56|07'" +
                                    "AND MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' " +
                                    "AND MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_CONTRACT.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' " +
                                    "AND MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR_XREF.HUB_STATE_IND = '1' " + 
                                    "AND MDMCUST_ORS.C_LU_CODES.HUB_STATE_IND = '1'" +
                                    "AND ROWNUM = 1";

try {
            querySingleView = emSingleView.createNativeQuery(sqlSingleViewQuery)
                                          .setParameter(1, sourceClientId)
                                          .setParameter(2, convertedClientId)
                                          .setParameter(3, policyNum);
            querySingleViewResult = (List<String>) querySingleView.getResultList();
        } catch (NoResultException nre) {
          // Issue a validation failure message to prevent query from continuing.
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed();
            // Display error message to user
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("fatcaSearchSingleViewFailMessage"));
            // Generate log entry on server
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, nre);
        }
        return querySingleViewResult;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
UPPER(MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_CONTRACT.SRC_POLICY_ID) = ? "
```

will most likely prevent Oracle from using an index on SRC_POLICY_ID. MIf it is an ID I would expect it to be a number so an UPPER should not be necessary. If you really do need the UPPER than you propably should create a function based index on the column.

But without access to the database performance issues are hard to solve.

P.S.: And do you really need the DISTINCT and ROWNUMBER=1. I think you should write the query that you get only one row by using the proper conditions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @flnhossfel Thank you! I will switch to using :value instead of "?" in the query. The client ID field can take alphanumeric characters, and has to be converted to uppercase. But, your point is well taken. I can address that using other options (such as converting to uppercase from a tag in the Primefaces code of this project). And I will also remove the rownum (it was left by mistake, I forgot to delete it). I will also see what happens without DISTINCT. Since it runs fast when I run it within DB Visualizer that the database is not the culprit as far as latency is concerned?

Comment: BRILLIANT! I removed UPPER and DISTINCT, the response has improved dramatically!! I don't fully understand why, but what matters is it has addressed the issue (I can always research it on my own to find out why). Many, many, many thanks for this fhossfel!!